# How to change Layout of Quasar App and put the left Drawer to the right?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am lost with the layout of **Quasar** and don't understand it, although I've read the documentation of it.

The scaffolder gave me the following code. But this makes the Drawer on the left side. How can I put it to the right side?

```
<template>
  <q-layout view="lHh Lpr lFf">
    <q-header elevated>
      <q-toolbar>
        <q-btn
          flat
          dense
          round
          icon="menu"
          aria-label="Menu"
          @click="leftDrawerOpen = !leftDrawerOpen"
        />

        <q-toolbar-title>
          Quasar App
        </q-toolbar-title>

        <div>Quasar v{{ $q.version }}</div>
      </q-toolbar>
    </q-header>

    <q-drawer
      v-model="leftDrawerOpen"
      show-if-above
      bordered
      content-class="bg-grey-1"
    >
      <q-list>
        <q-item-label
          header
          class="text-grey-8"
        >
          Essential Links
        </q-item-label>
        <EssentialLink
          v-for="link in essentialLinks"
          :key="link.title"
          v-bind="link"
        />
      </q-list>
    </q-drawer>

    <q-page-container>
      <router-view />
    </q-page-container>
  </q-layout>
</template>
```

I thought it has something to do with the letters in

However. Playing with them won't change anything.

I also tried to put the `q-drawer`-tag below the `q-page-container`, with no luck either.

How to make the drawer visible on the right side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the behavior to `side="right"`

https://quasar.dev/layout/drawer#QDrawer-API

```
<q-drawer
  v-model="leftDrawerOpen"
  side="right"
  show-if-above
  bordered
  content-class="bg-grey-1"
>
  <q-list>
    <q-item-label header class="text-grey-8">
      Essential Links
    </q-item-label>
    <EssentialLink
      v-for="link in essentialLinks"
      :key="link.title"
      v-bind="link"
    />
  </q-list>
</q-drawer>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!